# Why are some browser-native global objects written as window.object but others just as object?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Some browser-native global objects are written with `window` and others without.

[`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)
[`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle)
[`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)
[`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Why? What's the difference? This returns `true` for all cases.

```
'setTimeout' in window
'getComputedStyle' in window
'JSON' in window
'decodeURIComponent' in window
```

I first noticed an apparent difference when using [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/).

**Input**

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @output_file_name default.js
// @formatting pretty_print
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

window.decodeURIComponent;
window.getComputedStyle;
window.setTimeout;
window.JSON;
decodeURIComponent;
```

**Output**

```
window.a;
window.getComputedStyle;
window.setTimeout;
window.JSON;
decodeURIComponent;
```

It has `decodeURIComponent` [defined as an extern](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/externs/es3.js#88), but still renames it when used with `window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a good answer for this.

As you observed, in the Closure-compiler default externs, some of the objects are defined as properties on the window object, some are defined as global objects and some both. There really isn't a good reason for this - just that the externs were developed this way. The default externs evolve over time, so definitions are added as developers need them which begins to explain the current state.

A highly needed task is a method to generate the externs from the published IDL documents. However, this change will likely break existing code (default type names will probably change slightly) and to date there hasn't been a developer willing to take on the task.

*Update Note: It isn't really desirable to define ALL globals as both objects as well as properties on `window`. Such code would simply balloon the size of the default externs. However, commonly used externs should be defined on both.*

Developers are encouraged to use `VERBOSE` warnings so that the compiler will warn about undefined properties.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference. What you have to understand is JavaScript global scope.

Whenever I try to resolve a variable name, whatever that is, it is looked up the scope chain.

Imagine you had this:

```
function() {
    var k = 5;
    function() {
        (function() {
           k = 6;
        })();
    };
};
console.log(k);
```

So as you see, it doesn't really matter where it is placed, a higher order definition is "remembered", unless you override it manually.

Same happens with `setTimeout`. Wherever you place `setTimeout` in your code, regardless of how many times you nest it, JavaScript will look for it and find it in `window` and it will resolve it as such.

It makes no difference whether you type `window.something` or `something` because something will be resolved in global scope if it exists or will throw a `ReferenceError` if never found.

**Closure Compiler**(the above has nothing to do with the compiler's behaviour).

The Closure Compiler is dumb in that way, at least from a shallow perspective. The is no good way of telling it "Do not touch this property".

The simple way of preventing property renaming is to access it via `["property"]`. Allow me to demonstrate:

```
var a = {};
a["bla"] = "bla";// compiler will not touch this.
a.bla2 = "bla2"l;// compiler will flatten this!!
```

But you have to remember to **always access that property via `a["property"]`**, otherwise your call to `a.property` will be re-written to `a.ab` or whatever and fail!!

So now you need `window["decodeUriComponent"]` and everything will be fine. As weird as it is, it's the simplest possible trick. The Compiler will transform the above to `window.decodeUriComponent`, but it won't touch the actual name.

Comment: Agreed, but if the Closure Compiler is botching `window.decodeURIComponent` then it kind-of does matter ...

Comment: *"The is no good way of telling it "Do not touch this property"."*: That's actually what externs are for (if you are actually using an external API, or bracket notation, as you already said).

Comment: I don't know about native objects, but I have successfully used externs for D3.js calls. And the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#externs) is pretty clear about it: *"Solution for Calling out from Compiled Code to External Code: Externs"*. I don't know about the details, but proper type annotation might be necessary.